# Does concat return a Foldable?

Tags: haskell

```
Prelude> :t concat
concat :: Foldable t => t [a] -> [a]
```

Looking at the type information above, I understood that the value returned was not derived of the *Foldable* typeclass. So, in the code below, I was expecting the line *dd=concat [cc,aa]* to fail because cc is not a *Foldable*. But, as you can notice, it worked, why?

```
Prelude> aa = [1,2]
Prelude> bb=[3,4]
Prelude> cc = concat[aa,bb]
Prelude> dd=concat [cc,aa]
Prelude> dd
[1,2,3,4,1,2]
```

Thanks!

Comment: The foldable is the *outer* structure, so here a list.

Comment: `cc` is not an *arbitrary* foldable (which would be indicated by a type like, perhaps, `(Foldable t1, Foldable t2) => t1 [a] -> t2 a`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
concat :: Foldable t => t [a] -> [a]
```

The way we read this, `concat` takes a foldable collection of lists and returns a list. `t` could be substituted for a lot of things, so long as the resulting thing is foldable.

```
concat :: [[a]] -> [a]
concat :: ZipList [a] -> [a]
concat :: Set [a] -> [a]
```

These are all valid specializations of this function. So we could pass it a list of lists, a zip-list of lists, a set of lists, or any other of the myriad of containers available in the Haskell ecosystem.

Now, in your case, you make lists `aa` and `bb`. So<sup>1</sup>

```
aa :: [Int]
bb :: [Int]
```

Now, as we said, lists are foldable, so `[]` is a valid substitution for `t` in the type above. Then you do

```
let cc = concat [aa, bb]
```

You're passing a list of lists to `concat`, so the specific version you're using is

```
concat :: [[Int]] -> [Int]
```

and so `cc` has type

```
cc :: [Int]
```

Likewise, calling it with `[cc, aa]` causes no issues, as you're *still* passing a list of lists, so we're using the same specialization as before.

```
dd :: [Int]
```

I hope this helps! It can be confusing getting used to Haskell's infrastructure if you're used to a more "is-a" style relationship from OOP.

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm assuming type `Int` for simplicity. Strictly speaking, your variables, in full generality, have type `Num a => [a]` which, again, can be specialized to `[Int]`. But I imagine you were thinking of them as integers anyway, so this is beside the point.

Answer (score 3):

Every list is Foldable; there are other foldable types besides lists.  Other examples include `Vector` and `Seq`.  `concat` always returns a list.

The input to `concat` is `Foldable t => t [a]`.  One type that satisfies the `Foldable` constraint is `[[Int]]` - lists of (lists of integers).  Another would be `Vector [Int]`.  The inside is always list, but the outside can vary.

In both of your calls to `concat`, you pass a `[[Int]]` - the named inner lists `aa`, `bb`, `cc`, and the outer set of `[]` on the line with `concat`.

`cc` has the same type as `aa` or `bb`.  I've been writing this as `[Int]`.  GHCi will give the more general type `Num a => [a]`, meaning a list of `a` for any numeric type you like - `Int`, `Float`, `Double`, `Integer`.